# LINQ to EF4 Query Where clause not filtering as expected

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-4

I've googled for this but can't find anything obviously related, so posting here for some insight. Using LINQ / EF4. Here's the code snippet:

```
 private const string JOB_FAILED = "Failed";
// other code..

var successfulJobs = context.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status != JOB_FAILED);
                foreach (Job successfulJob in successfulJobs)
                {
                    context.DeleteObject(successfulJob);
                }
```

I would expect successfulJobs to contain all jobs where Job.Status != "Failed". However, the code witihn foreach{} executes when Job.Status DOES equal "Failed". Am I missing something fundamental here about LINQ\Lambda?

EDIT: Generated SQL as requested, seems ok.

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Parameters] AS [Parameters], 
[Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
[Extent1].[Created] AS [Created], 
[Extent1].[Modified] AS [Modified]
FROM [bws].[JobRunner_Tasks] AS [Extent1]
WHERE N'Failed' <> [Extent1].[Status]
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL being executed? You can capture that using SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: Try making a case-insensitive comparison: `var successfulJobs = context.Jobs.Where(x => String.Compare(x.Status, JOB_FAILED, true) != 0) `

Comment: Tried as you suggested, but I'm still getting the same issue

Comment: Have you run the generated SQL itself in SSMS? What results does it come back with?

I created a quick database with your table and realized I needed to move from the `dbo` schema to the `bws` schema. Is there any possibility that you may have the same table in both schemas?

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm.... in any other language, I might suggest using

```
x => !x.Status.equals(JOB_FAILED)
```

but I didn't think string comparison was that finicky in C#

Answer (score 0):

I would still say it's a case sensitive issue.
What does the query return if you run it directly in SQL?
Can you maybe post a sample of the data in that table? (Including "Failed" statuses)
I know this isn't an answer but i can't add comments to the post yet (rep below 50).